# Very basic Circuit Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image: Circuit Image]

My Question is how would find the current of the ammeter

I tried to solve by making 4 ohm and 8 ohm, which I believe are parallel as one effective resistance, and making 6 and 12 ohms which I believe are parallel as one effective resistance, and diving the total of the two effective resistance by the total voltage, but by doing so, I can only find the total current in the circuit, whereas I need the current in the branch containing the ammeter.

The answer says "balanced wheatstone bridge, I = 0" I do not quite understand.